# How to force aliases for columns in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I got this message:

**SAWarning: Column 'id_usuario' on table  being replaced by Column('id_usuario', Integer(), table=, primary_key=True, nullable=False), which has the same key.  Consider use_labels for select() statements.**

My models are:

```
from settings import DATABASE

engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://%s:%s@%s/%s?charset=utf8' % (DATABASE["username"], DATABASE["password"], DATABASE["host"], DATABASE["database"]))
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

metadata = MetaData()
Base = declarative_base(metadata=metadata)

class UserSearch(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user_search'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    id_usuario = Column("id_usuario", Integer, ForeignKey("usuario.id_usuario"))
    user = relationship("User", lazy=False, innerjoin=True)
    #...

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'usuario'

    id_usuario = Column("id_usuario", Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    #...
```

I use a query like this:

```
session.query(UserSearch).filter(UserSearch.category == 'hotel')
```

The generated query is:

```
SELECT user_search.id, user_search.id_usuario, usuario_1.id_usuario
FROM user_search JOIN usuario AS usuario_1 ON usuario_1.id_usuario = user_search.id_usuario WHERE user_search.category = 'hotel'
```

So, I want to figure out how to get the query which columns are aliased, like:

```
SELECT user_search.id as user_search_1_id, user_search.id_usuario as user_search_1_id_usuario, usuario_1.id_usuario as user_1_id_usuario
FROM user_search JOIN usuario AS usuario_1 ON usuario_1.id_usuario = user_search.id_usuario WHERE user_search.category = 'hotel'
```

I have noticed MANY examples in SQLAlchemy docs with generated queries  like this one.
I didn't follow the tip in warning ("Consider use_labels for select() statements) because - I think - I'm using Query objects no select() expresions. Maybe this is the point and I'm wrong.

**Could anyone help me ?**

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 with Python 3.5.1 + mysqlclient==1.3.7 SQLAlchemy==1.0.13

Comment: SQLAlchemy 2.0 does not emit a warning for this code - looks like the labels are generated automatically.